# Customizing Native Calendar view of SharePoint 2010/ 2013

Tags: web-part, list-view, calendar, view, sharepoint-calendar

I am designing a Training calendar. Instead of designing an entirely new webpart, I want to utilize the existing calendar given by SharePoint.

1. I need to replace "+Add" button from each day in monthly calendar
   view with "Enroll Me" button.
2. Clicking this "Enroll Me" would open a
   custom new form which would push entries to lists on submit.

Is it possible to customize the default calendar to such extent? Where can I find the design of the native calendar given by SharePoint? If not, then please suggest other options to achieve the solution.